# Как обменять значения двух переменных?

Tags: java

Как можно обменять значения двух переменных в Java?
(кроме таких способов):

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
int tmp;
tmp = a;
a = b;`
b = tmp;

a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

Comment: 2-й способ подходит только для типов, у которых определена операция сложения и вычитания, а Вы говорите об обмене переменных, а не чисел. Кроме того, 2-й способ может привести к переполнению целого числа, либо к чуть другому числу (в случае чисел с плавающей запятой)

Answer (score 2):

Для обмена целочисленных переменных алгоритм обмена при помощи исключающего ИЛИ (без ввода третьей переменной) выглядит следующим образом:

```
int a = -5;
int b = 9;

a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

В этом случае после выполнения программы `a` будет равно 9, а `b` будет равно -5.

Можно, впрочем, сделать то же самое, только ещё короче:

```
a = a ^ b ^ (b = a);
```

Обмен строк без ввода третьей переменной можно сделать так:

```
String a = "first";
String b = "second";
a = a + b;
b = a.substring(0, (a.length() - b.length()));
a = a.substring(b.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Через исключающее или, только эта операция будет либо сопоставима по ресурсам, либо перевышать ее

[Алгоритм обмена при помощи исключающего ИЛИ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%98)

Comment: ответ должен содержать решение проблемы, а не ссылку на сторонний ресурс. Ссылку на ресурс можно добавить в качестве дополнения к ответу, раскрывающего некоторые детали.